# Handling Button states

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

Hello I have another problem/question. I have a custom control with a button on it:

[image]

I want to delete an image from it, so I removed the reference from Attributes inspector -> Image, so now my button in designer looks like this:

[image]

But when I launch it on simulator, when I press the button (just push it, not making a click ) the image shows up! Where does it come from? Are there any button states styles in project files, where this could be written?

Because button has two references - 1 outlet and 1 action and none of those are used to add image to the button! I just don't understand where from the image gets in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the image for both normal and selected states of the button from the attribute inspector(check stateConfig attribute).

Comment: Just found those properties, i knew that they must be somewhere =) Thanks.